# Customer Load() returning code:0 for valid user

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

I was trying to load customer based on entity id for an api and tried to print it in postman. The user entity id is valid but it is throwing some exception during loading.

Can anyone help me identify why this is happening? Any help would me appreciated.

I am attaching the screenshot of the code snippet and postman response below.

PS: tried echoing $customerData->getId(), it is valid.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. It was the problem with "localhost". In post man api URL, i replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to better properly check whether the `$customerData->getId()` is not empty or null, Like:

```
if(!is_null($customerData->getId())){...}
```

Comment: I have checked it. $customerData->getId() has the value 16